# Converting from log to linear in C and taking average

Tags: c, logging, floating-point, double, coercion

I don't know C well at all, and I'm trying to edit someone's code, but I'm having issues when trying to convert values from the log to linear domains.

For example, let's say we have an array A that is full of log values equal to -100 dB, i.e.

```
float A[100];
int i;

for( i=0; i<100; i++ )
    A[i] = -100;
```

What I want to do is find the average of all the values (which clearly is -100), but by taking the average in the linear and not log domain, i.e.

```
float tmp_avg = 0.0;
float avg;
int count = 0;

for( i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
    tmp_avg += pow(10.0, A[i]/10.0);
    count++;
}

avg = 10*log10(tmp_avg / count);
```

However, the result I'm getting is all 0's.  Now the code I'm working on is much more complex than this, but I was wondering if there's anything obvious that I'm missing as to why this won't work.

One thought I had is that 10^(-100/10) is a very small value (1e-10), and perhaps too small to be accurately defined as a float.  I've tried making it a double instead, but I still get a result of all 0's.

Thanks!

Comment: That code (or rather, a version of that code that compiles) [works fine](http://ideone.com/GlvTG).  Your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Your program works fine here - `avg` comes out as `-100`.  I did have to fix a variable name typo in your last calculation, but other than that it's fine.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me too when I used an online compiler, so not sure why it isn't working on my device.  Perhaps some subroutine is defining float variables in such a way that it can't handle very small numbers.

Comment: What device / compiler is this on?

Comment: It's embedded into a piece of equipment that we deploy out to sea.  However, I didn't write the code so it's very difficult for me to debug this.  I basically have to set it up to collect data, then look at the final output.  That said, I know that everything works as long as I don't convert from log to linear.

Comment: @Josiah: You should create a standalone minimal test-case (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: If it's for an embedded system, possibly the floating point types are unusually small like 16-bit half-precision?  You might try adding an offset to bring the numbers closer to zero before converting to linear, then subtracting the same offset from the result after averaging (if the values fall into a narrow enough range).

Comment: Assuming some kind of standards compliance - check FLT_MIN, FLT_MIN_10_EXP.  I think Dmitri is probably correct.  Check your float.h include file, if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what the problem was:  I needed to include the math.h library at the top of the program:

```
#include <math.h>
```

Without that, I believe that there was no reference for the log10 function, which in turn caused the result to be all 0's.  I now include math.h and everything seems to be working fine.